# Spark - convert scala to java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

Using `apache-spark` to process data.

Given such `scala` codes:

```
val rdd1 = sc.cassandraTable("player", "playerinfo").select("key1", "value")
val rdd2 = rdd1.map(row => (row.getString("key1"), row.getLong("value")))
```

Basically, it covert a `RDD` 'rdd1' to another `RDD` 'rdd2', but it stores 'rdd1' as key-value pair form.

Pay attention that the source data is from `cassandra` and `keys1` is a part of composite key and `value` is the value.

Then how to convert this into `Java` so that I will have a `JavaPairRDD<String,Long>` using spark Java API? I already have an `cassandraRowsRDD` generated successfully from the Java codes below:

```
  JavaRDD<String> cassandraRowsRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("player", "playerinfo")
            .map(new Function<CassandraRow, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(CassandraRow cassandraRow) throws Exception {
                    return cassandraRow.toString();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CassandraJavaRDD` inherits `mapToPair` methods. You can call it to get key-value pair RDD in Java.

```
    JavaPairRDD<String, String> cassandraKeyValuePairs = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("player", "playerinfo").mapToPair(
            new PairFunction<CassandraRow, String, String>() {
                @Override
                public Tuple2<String, String> call(CassandraRow row) throws Exception {
                    return new Tuple2(row.getString("key1"), row.getLong("value"));
                }
            }
    );
```

You can also call the function on your `cassandraRowsRDD`.